# Dirichlet series $\sum a_n n^{-x}$ where $(a_1+\dots+a_n)/n \rightarrow A$

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, dirichlet-series

I am working on some Dirichlet series and I am familiar with the proofs of convergence of the functions $\zeta$ and $\eta$.

And I was wondering if $g(x)=\sum a_n n^{-x}$ was normally convergent on $[a,b]$ where $1<a<b$ under the assumption that $(a_1+\dots+a_n)/n$ converges to a given value A.

Thus I would be able to prove that $g$ is infinitely differentiable on $]1,+\infty[$ (It is my final goal and I can clearly see how to do all the other steps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial summation
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} a_n n^{-s}=\lim_{N\to \infty}( A(N)N^{-s}+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}A(n)(n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s}))$$
For $s > 1$ using that $n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s}=\int_n^{n+1} s t^{-s-1}dt\le sn^{-s-1}$ it is clear that it converges if $A(N)/N$ is bounded.

Comment: Thank you very much I see it now

Comment: But we have only showed the Pointwise convergence this way not the normal convergence right ?

Comment: It converges locally uniformly (it may be unbounded as $s\to 1$), same for the derivative, same for $\Re(s) > 1$, thus it is holomorphic and analytic there. You can also show directly that it is analytic on $s>1$ by expanding $t^{-s-h} = \sum_{k\ge 0} h^k \frac{(-\log t)^kt^{-s} }{k!} $ then changing the order of summation using absolute convergence of the obtained double series for $|h|<s-1$